# Macro SWAP(t,x,y) exchanging two arguments of type t

Tags: c, pointers, swap, c-preprocessor

So I am basically trying to make a SWAP(t,x,y) macro that exchanges two arguments of type t. I am trying to think of going around the problem when these two arguments are of the form

v[i++] and w[f(x)] , i.e. SWAP(int, v[i++], w[f(x)]).

The code below is basically crashing ...

```
#define SWAP(T,x,y) {T *p = x; T *q = y; T z = *p; *p = *q; *q = z;}

int f (int x){
    return (0-x);
}

int main(void) {

int v[] = {1,2,3};
int i = 0;

int w[] = {4,5,6};
int x = -1;

int *p = v;
int *q = w;

SWAP(int*, v[i++],w[f(x)]);

return 0;
}
```

Any ideas what may go wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SWAP(int*, v[i++],w[f(x)]);
```

`v[i++]` is an `int` element but you are assigning it to a pointer object in:

```
T *p = x;
```

so when are you are dereferencing `p` in `T z = *p;` you get a segfault. If you want a pointer to the element use the `&` operator.

Moreover `v[i++]` has a side-effect (it modifies `i++`) and you should never pass expressions that have side-effects in a macro call.

Comment: thanks. now it's all fine! the 'side-effect' issue is the real problem here, that I was trying to get round.

Comment: if either of the arguments are `p` - this will fail (not my down vote though). Included own answer below.

Answer (score 3):

```
#define SWAP(T,x,y) {T *p = &(x); T *q = &(y); T z = *p; *p = *q; *q = z;}
...
    SWAP(int, v[i++], w[f(x)]);
```

Comment: It would be better to quote the macro parameter names where possible: `#define SWAP(T, x, y) { T *p = &(x), *q = &(y), z = *p; *p = *q; *q = z; }`. This reduces errors that occur when the text substitution of macros interacts with C syntax.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It is a good  point because result may vary by operator precedence. 
It was fixed. thanks.

Comment: I`ve tested the code but somehow it does not swap ints. I`ve tried chars, floats and even char* strings but for int it does not work. How come?

Comment: @IlianZapryanov ; It has worked well in places that I've tried. 
I think you are writing the code by mistake probably. , 
Do you write any code?、

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yes, I`ve write it by hand. I`ll rewrite it again and will report asap the error message from GCC.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY `setbits.c: In function ‘main’:
setbits.c:3:32: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 #define SWAP(T, A, B) { T* a = &(A); T* b = &(B); T t = *a; \
                                ^
setbits.c:11:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘SWAP’
  SWAP(int, a, b);
  ^
setbits.c:3:45: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
 #define SWAP(T, A, B) { T* a = &(A); T* b = &(B); T t = *a; \
                                             ^
setbits.c:11:2: note: in expansion of macro ‘SWAP’
  SWAP(int, a, b);
  ^
`

Comment: @IlianZapryanov `incompatible pointer type` : It seems you're using a variable of a different type.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY OK, I agree I am messing something, but how it works for char* strings, floats, char symbols and just not for ints???

Comment: @IlianZapryanov ; yes.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Here is a simple output assume that a is always lower value and SWAP is called before the fprintf():
a: 10 b:20 
af:40.000000 bf:20.000000
stra: StringB strb: StringA

Comment: @BLUEPIXY I saw it - now that is interesting: http://ideone.com/F8ANqz
take a look at it. I`ve rewrite your code with just change of var names and see the compiler error.

Comment: ,@IlianZapryanov ; it's not error. but Names are colliding.  to fix E.g `#define SWAP(T,x,y)  {T *_a = &(x); T *_b = &(y); T _z = *_a; *_a = *_b; *_b = _z;}` //Not used names that begin with an underscore have been reserved. It may be a unique anyway.

Comment: @IlianZapryanov ; _a and b could be reserved._ no, no. name start with `_ ` e.g `_a`. or use unique name. e.g `q_d_ick2. or change to function.

Answer (score 0):

This solution avoids side-effects by only instansiating the argument once and shadowing by reusing `SWAP` as an identifier.

```
#define SWAP(type, a_, b_) \
do { \
    struct { type *a; type *b; type t; } SWAP; \
    SWAP.a  = &(a_); \
    SWAP.b  = &(b_); \
    SWAP.t  = *SWAP.a; \
    *SWAP.a = *SWAP.b; \
    *SWAP.b = SWAP.t; \
} while (0)
```