# Portable C SWAP macro which doesn't require a 'type' argument and doesn't use memcpy

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, c89

Swap macro's which take a type are fairly well known.

```
#define SWAP(type, a_, b_) do {        \
    type SWAP, *a = &(a_), *b = &(b_); \
    SWAP = *a;                         \
    *a = *b;                           \
    *b = SWAP;                         \
} while (0)
```

also:
[Macro SWAP(t,x,y) exchanging two arguments of type t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16377475)

Is it possible to implement this functionality while being...

- portable (no compiler specific `typeof`)
- without using function calls such as `memcpy`
  (which isn't assured to get optimized out, *it wasn't in my tests at least*)

---

I came up with a *flawed* method which uses a struct, defined to be the size of the input.

```
#define SWAP(a_, b_) do \
{ \
    struct { \
        char dummy_data[sizeof(a_)]; \
    } SWAP, *a = (void *)(&(a_)), *b = (void *)(&(b_)); \
    /* ensure sizes match */ \
    { char t[(sizeof(a_) == sizeof(*a)) ? 1 : -1]; (void)t; } \
    /* check types are compatible */ \
    (void)(0 ? (&(a_) == &(b_)) : 0); \
    SWAP = *a; \
    *a = *b; \
    *b = SWAP; \
} while (0)
```

... but it can fail if the temporary `struct` gets padded by the compiler *(Depending on GCC's `__packed__` would work but then its no longer portable)
It also may have issue with alignment depending on the architecture*.

Comment: Interesting question but why?

Comment: Why no `memcpy()` but assignment is ok?

Comment: Your approach also produces undefined behavior, due to an aliasing violation.

Comment: `struct` with just one field will never have padding, the first field is guaranteed to be at the start address of the `struct`.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt, interesting - is this a part of the C spec? or it just happens to be true mostly? - asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29195926

Comment: This is part of the standard, since always. It says: *There may be unnamed
padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.*

Comment: @Jens Gustedt: I agree about the lack of padding at the start of the structure, but what about padding at the end of this structure? Imagine a target where all structures are aligned on the maximum alignment.  On such an architecture, the `SWAP` structure could have some padding inserted at the end. Would such a feature be OK with the  C Standard or not? Can you give references to support it?

Comment: Padding at the end is not relevant for you approach, it just gets copied along if it suits the compiler. What is more relevant is Sneftel's comment that you are violating strict aliasing rules, so the behavior of your code is undefined.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20380289/1505939) is my favourite answer to this problem. I'm tempted to chose this thread as duplicate, it doesn't really add anything new unless you can post *proof* in the form of good benchmarks that there is something wrong with the `memcpy` versions.

Comment: @Matt McNabb, I saw this answer and tried using it already, But GCC wasn't optimizing out the `memcpy` calls.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt, any extra padding added to the struct would mean extra bytes get copied into the input arguments. (past their end-points).

Comment: @ideasman42 have you run benchmarks to check the performance?

Comment: @Matt McNabb, I'll have to do some, but its reasonable to assume 3x function calls of `memcpy` to swap a `char` or `int` for eg, is going to be slower. Also my question is rather different to http://stackoverflow.com/a/20380289/1505939 - even if there is some overlap with the answers.

Comment: If the compiler does not generate optimal code then it should be considered a compiler bug; you could post a new thread including a MCVE demonstrating the problem (include your compiler flags and corresponding assembly)

Comment: Your question is "Portable C SWAP macro which doesn't require a 'type' argument" and the linked thread (and its duplicate) have lots of answers giving a portable C swap macro that doesn't require a type argument.

Comment: @Matt McNabb, all of them require compiler extensions or use `memcpy`.

Comment: That's because those are the only ways of doing it. Also , "not using memcpy" is a spurious requirement IMO

Comment: @Matt McNabb, if this is true - then the answer to my question is "No". Just because the question has a negative answer doesn't mean it shouldn't be asked.

Answer (score 1):

I am curious to know under which circumstances such a structure would get padded, and whether such padding would be conformant.

You can add a static check for `sizeof(SWAP) == sizeof(a_)` and use `memcpy` if the test fails (padding was inserted at the end of the `SWAP` structure).

Also do not use simple names such as `a` and `b` in the body of the macro as they could be macro expanded if the user defined these identifiers as macros.  Using `a` and `b` as macro arguments does not pose a problem.

```
#define SWAP(a, b) do {                             \
    struct {                                        \
        char a_[sizeof(a)];                         \
    } SWAP, *a_ = (void *)&(a), *b_ = (void *)&(b); \
        if (sizeof(SWAP) == sizeof(a)) {            \
            SWAP = *a_; *a_ = *b_; *b_ = SWAP;      \
        } else if (a_ != b_) {                      \
            memcpy(&SWAP, a_, sizeof(a));           \
            memcpy(a_, b_, sizeof(a));              \
            memcpy(b_, &SWAP, sizeof(a));           \
        }                                           \
    } while (0)
```

You might want to add a check for `sizeof(a) == sizeof(b)` as a poor mans attempt to type checking this overworked macro.

Comment: In my current macro I have type checking, just removed from the example to make it shorter.

Comment: According to @Jens Gustedt, the struct wont ever be padded. Interested to find if this is apart of the C spec - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29195926

Comment: This code fails if `a` and `b` are the same object (since the source and destination of `memcpy` overlap).

Comment: @Anonymous: good point! `memcpy(a_, b_, sizeof(a));` invokes undefined behaviour. What about `*a_ = *b_;` in this case?  Is `x=x;` always OK for all non void data types of `x`?

Comment: You could just add an extra branch to check for identity and do nothing

Comment: `x = x;` is always fine unless `x` is indeterminate of course