# Struct padding for single member structs

Tags: c, struct, padding

I was looking to make a struct which was an arbitrary size, known at compile time. (for use in a macro).

eg:

```
/* assume sizeof(SomeStruct) could be an odd number,
 * if it is using GCC's 'packed' attribute for eg */
struct {
    unsigned char data[sizeof(SomeStruct)];
} a, *tmp;

tmp = (void *)some_data
a = *tmp;
```

However I was concerned that `struct` padding may increase the size of the `struct` so it is larger than the member, I was assured that the size of a single member `struct` will always be the size of its member.

So my question is:

Can I rely on single member structs *always* being the same size as their member? Is this apart of the C spec? or is it just how most compilers behave?

Comment: I have seen compilers pad things in objects that only have a single member. so I guess not. no hard references though.

Comment: 4th comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192256 by @Jens Gustedt, says there wont be padding, but didnt reference a source. I checked in Linux/GCC and found odd numbers didn't pad, but that doesn't mean it will work the same on all other platforms/architectures.

Comment: @Hans Passant, for defining a temp storage struct - see example of a `SWAP` macro - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29192256/portable-c-swap-macro-which-doesnt-require-a-type-argument

Comment: Declare a union instead, where one member is SomeStruct and the other is data[1].

Comment: Or a union with a single member can work too.

Answer (score 6):

[C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.7.2.1 paragraph 17:

> There may be unnamed padding at the end of a structure or union.

No special case is listed for structs with only one member. This is implementation-defined.

It's not obvious why a compiler *would* put padding there though, since the size of the member should already be as padded as is necessary for all purposes, as it has a complete type of its own.

---

For your usage though, you don't need to rely on the compiler's behaviour - you can enforce it yourself by adding a static assertion to your macro that `sizeof *tmp == sizeof (SomeStruct)`. If you have an up-to-date compiler and your macro allows for declaration statements, just use `_Static_assert`; there are also several C99-compatible hacks you can use, such as:

```
#define STATIC_EXPR_ASSERT(COND) (sizeof (char[(COND) ? 1 : -1]))
```

... which you can use as the lhs of a comma-expression.

You should also note that if the body of the temporary struct is made up of a char array, it may not have sufficient alignment to represent the incoming data correctly. From C11 onwards you should specify the alignment of the array with `_Alignas`:

```
struct {
    _Alignas (max_align_t) unsigned char data[sizeof(SomeStruct)];
} a, *tmp;
```

...which will ensure it can safely store the data for any type regardless of alignment. In C99 you don't have any way to explicitly request max alignment, but you can force the alignment to match a named type by making the temporary struct a member of a union alongside it (you might try `long double` and hope that's the most-aligned type).

Comment: Say `struct{char foo;}Foo;`, then `sizeof(Foo)` can be larger than `sizeof(char)`. Because the compiler is free to set alignment for `Foo` at any boundary, but to enforce `sizeof(Foo[N])==N*sizeof(Foo)`, it has to pad at the end.

Comment: Do any compilers do this?

Comment: @ideasman42 I doubt it, but it's possible that someone is doing so either to support special cases (perhaps as a pre-C11 alignment annotation?), or in the case of very naive compilers/interpreters simply giving all structs max-alignment for the sake of simplicity.