# Can an array of single-member structure objects be interpreted as an array of their subobjects?

Tags: arrays, c, casting, language-lawyer, pointer-arithmetic

In the following program, an array of objects of structure type, wherein each object comprises a sole subobject of type `int`, is initialized by a function which treats it as an array of `int`s:

```
#define N 8
void init_arr(int* arr)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        arr[i] = i;
}
int main()
{
    struct { int i; } arr[N];
    init_arr((int*)arr);
}
```

Is this well-defined in C?

My suspicion is that the cast of `arr` to `int*` in the call to `init_arr` is well-defined (per C99 6.3.2.1.3 [array-to-pointer conversion] followed by 6.7.2.1.13 [structure-member pointer interconvertibility]), but results in a pointer to a member subobject, not an array element. Even if such an object is treated as the element of a single-element array (for the purposes of pointer arithmetic), subscripting on its pointer produces a defined result only when the index is 0. Is my understanding correct? Is there any way to make this well-defined without modifying `init_arr` or resorting to passing a plain array of `int`s (then copying to `arr` element by element)?

Bonus: What about in C++?

Comment: Structures can have padding, even if there's just one member, so an array of structures may have different padding from an array of ints.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29195926/struct-padding-for-single-member-structs

Comment: @Barmar Indeed, but what if I ensured that it didn't (via implementation-specific features and/or `static_assert`)? Can I avoid the scenario where I must initialize `arr` by element-wise copy of a separate `int` array?

Comment: If you're using implementation-dependent features then you can do whatever works with that implementation, the C specification doesn't matter.

Comment: Declaring the structure packed would almost certainly do what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Struct padding for single member structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29195926/struct-padding-for-single-member-structs)

Comment: _Is my understanding correct?_ Yes (also, you can add `1`, but not access through such pointer), and (the absence of) padding is not relevant.

Comment: @thebusybee No, since, as Language Lawyer mentioned, the presence or absence of padding does not change the fact that the posted code is (apparently) undefined. That said, I do understand that the _possibility_ of there being padding could be a rationale.